# including multiple copies of the same model in the file.world?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way to include multiple copies of the same model with different position in the world file?

For example:
I have the coke_can model, that I want to include multiple copies of it in my world file as following:

```
  <include>
      <uri>model://coke_can</uri>
      <pose>-0.0 -2 0 0 0 0</pose>
   </include>

    <include>
        <uri>model://coke_can</uri>
        <pose>-0.0 -5 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
```

but when I do this , the first model overrides the second one. In other words , only the first model shows up in the world file.

Any ideas or suggestions to solve this are very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3062/including-multiple-copies-of-the-same-model-in-the-file.world??/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use the `<name>` tag to give different names to each model. e.g.

```
<include>
    <uri>model://coke_can</uri>
    <name>coke1</name>
    <pose>-0.0 -2 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>

<include>
    <uri>model://coke_can</uri>
    <name>coke2</name>
    <pose>-0.0 -5 1 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-05-31**:
Thanks a lot. it works!

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3132/vvyogi/) on 2017-03-26**:
Can something similar be done from the world launch file?